# Difference between int num(5); and int num=5; What does int num(5); mean?

Tags: c++

I have noticed that both `int num(5)` and `int num = 5` both compile and assign 5 to `num`.

**Questions**

1. Could you help me understand why int `num(5)` work? This syntax looks like initializing an object
2. What is the difference between the two in terms of speed and stuff that goes behind

Pardon me if it's a silly question. I am a noob at C++ and in process to learn stuff.

Comment: For speed there should be no difference if you are using any common compiler that optimises the code.

Comment: Personally I do not know the exact difference the syntax implies, I remember seeing a rule that using `int num{5}` is the best way to create a variable but I do not remember why.

Comment: This video [The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs) by Nicolai Josuttis goes through all the different ways you can do initialization in C++.

Comment: Thank you Eljay. I'll go through it :)

Comment: From testing just now, both create the exact same assembly, as I expected (although this is my first time generating assembly so I might have made a mistake).

Comment: @ColonD I would recommend https://godbolt.org/ for inspecting compiler output.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thank you for the recommendation, it seems to produce a nicer to look at assembly than Visual Studio does

Comment: Oh wow it evens lets you hover over lines to see it's assembly. Regardless of syntax, it gets compiled down to `mov     dword ptr [rbp - 4], 5`

Answer (score 3):

> Could you help me understand why int num(5) work? This syntax looks
> like initializing an object

For the basic case (where the programmer explicitly types in a line of code like `int num(5);` or `int num = 5;`, having two different syntaxes that both do the same thing seems unnecessary, and it is.

However, once you get into templates, you'll find cases where you want to write a template that can work with both user-defined classes and with the built-in types.  For example, here is a template I wrote the other day to save (and later restore) the state of an arbitrary value:

```
template<class T> class SaveGuard
{
public:
   SaveGuard(T & saveMe) : _saveMe(saveMe), _tempHolder(saveMe) {/* empty */}  // save the current value
   ~SaveGuard() {_saveMe = _tempHolder;}  // restore the saved value

private:
   T & _saveMe;
   T _tempHolder;
};
```

Note that in this case, the `_tempHolder(saveMe)` clause is syntactically the same as the `int(5)` syntax, and since the `int(5)` syntax is supported, I can declare a `SaveGuard<int> guard(blah);` in my program and it will work as expected.  Alternatively I can declare a `SaveGuard<MyClassType> guard(blah);` and the template will work for that as well, using the copy-constructor of the `MyClassType` class.

> What is the difference between the two in terms of speed and stuff
> that goes behind

There's no difference in speed in your example; the compiler will generate the same assembly code for either syntax.

Comment: Useful references : `int num(5);` is [Direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) and `int num = 5;` is [Copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). They are indeed identical for `int`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clarification. Shall I delete the question because it's duplicate or shall I let it be ?

Comment: @AshutoshBhushan It is helpful to leave duplicates. It acts as "sign posts" for other users who would otherwise maybe not find the question that this question is a duplicate of.

Comment: Okay, understood :D